# statuspage io json parse

Tags: json, ajax

I am just wanting to output text from a json file to html, api is here: https://shopify.statuspage.io/api

```js
function setup() {
  loadJSON("https://d33g96wd23dd.statuspage.io/api/v2/summary.json", gotData, 'jsonp');
}

function gotData(data) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  output.innerHTML = data.status + ' ' + data.description;
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container w3-center" id="output"></div>
```

Comment: And... what did you try? Or what's the problem with it?

Comment: Where's the implementation of `loadJSON`? You don't call `setup` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code if you want to render the first element of the array

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var output = document.getElementById('output');
  $.getJSON( "https://d33g96wd23dd.statuspage.io/api/v2/summary.json", function( data ) {

  output.innerHTML = data.components[0].status + ' ' + data.components[0].description;
});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="w3-container w3-center" id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

else , you can loop up your append method alternately .